# Magento 1.9 with PHP 5.5 and Mcrypt 2.6.8

Tags: php, macos, apache, magento, mcrypt

I have installed mcrypt 2.6.8 with

> brew install php55-mcrypt

When I checked

> php -i

I see that mcrypt is installed and enabled.

However, Magento still claims that mcrypt module is not loaded.

I wonder if Magento 1.9 is not compatible with the latest mcrypt.

Is there anyway I can tweek the Magento source code to make it recognize mcrypt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your web server is using a different version of PHP than the version used on the  command line.  Try a call to `phpinfo()` from a web context.

Comment: Indeed Apache is using a different version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Even though brew installed PHP 5.5, Apache is still using the PHP 5.4 that was shipped with the OS.
This fixes the problem by installing the newer PHP and replacing the stock one.
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-to-php-5-4-or-5-5-mac-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to follow the below steps and check, as it worked for me,

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo restart apache2 //restart apache
```

It worked for me!

Comment: Hi Huzefam, my problem was because the system was using PHP 5.5, and all my module installations go there. However, the Apache is using PHP 5.4, so it was reading a wrong php.ini file.